# Get Address of Variadic Variadic Template?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

```
template<typename R, typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
void Func(R (*)(Args1...), Args2...)
{ // ...
}

template<typename R, typename... Args>
void Init(R(*)(Args...))
{
    // the second list is all of same types (a generic "any" type), just need same number as Args
    auto ptr = &Func<R, Args..., (Misc<Args>::type)...>;

    // ...
}


Init(&somefunc); // usage
```

Code kind of speaks for itself, I'm not sure how to separate the two so that they don't end up being concatenated to one variadic argument. I've tried using another class that holds a single single list of types and then `Func` would simply take 3 parameters but I keep getting explicit template error.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: @texasbruce The error was ambiguous, "illegal use of explicit template arguments", can't partial specialize a template function...

Comment: "Code speaks for itself" --> Not really.

Comment: I would think you need a `typename` before `Misc<Args>::type`.

Comment: @EduardoLeón If you don't understand templates or the syntax, then no.

Comment: I do understand templates. I like using template-heavy libraries like `Boost.Phoenix` and `Boost.Spirit` in my own work.

Comment: @EduardoLeón Using != Creating your own.

Comment: Believe me, it takes more C++ template knowledge to use those libraries than it takes to create your own toy templates.

Comment: @EduardoLeón I wasn't talking about toy templates, though i'd love to see you to try and recreate those libraries. I doubt you'd be able to.

Comment: To make this code compilable write `typename Misc<Args>::type...` instead of `(Misc<Args>::type)...`. Is it important that `Args2` are not the same types as `Args1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such function declaration

```
template<typename R, typename... Args1, typename... Args2>
void Func(R (*)(Args1...), Args2...)
{ // ...
}
```

can only be instantiated by deducing the template parameter from the argument. 
But do you really need Args1? What about:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args2>
void Func(R, Args2...)
{ // ...
}

template<typename R>
R Init(R)
{
  // instantiate Func<>(R, int, float, int)
  auto ptr = &Func<R, int, float, int>;

  // ...
  return ptr;
}


void foo(int, float) {
//
}


int main() {
  Init(foo);
}
```

Comment: Then provide a more complete use case, it is difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve...